# FEC decoder processing delays

Tags: digital-communications

I am trying to implement a burst demodulator. I have catered bits in premable for carrier and timing recovery and for fec also

in the recieve side if i am using viterbi decoder/TPC coder will the processing add any extra processing time. So if my burst time is say 1 ms. Is it possible to decode inside the 1ms or will there be any processing delays?

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, everything that you can calculate needs some time to calculate. Viterbi is quite well-behaved with respect to that, since you can decode up to the last couple of bits (only the last *constraint length* bits are relevant to the current decision), and you can already prepare the path metrics while receiving sequentially, and only need to do the backtracking after reception of the last code bit.

However, in most practical systems, you'd want some sort of interleaving. Also, you'll have filtering and all sorts of operations with inherent delay before you even decode. So, there's group delay and processing latency in your system anyway.
That, together with the fact that Viterbi is not an overly complex method and typically not used with convolutional codes with very large constraint lengths, and that 1 ms is a rather long time for a modern processing system:

You are probably barking up the wrong tree. You haven't defined acceptable latency yet, nor the length of your burst, nor the degree of error correction you need.

Start with that, and figure out (we'll be glad to help) whether processing delays will be a problem or not, before worrying about your decoder.

Comment: Consider if it is a burst in a particular slor of say TDMA slot. So i am assuming i have to do all the processing by the end of the slot. With viterbi increase in backtracing depth the latency increases. so the processing of the complete data may spill over to the next slot?  Just wanted to know how practically processing happens

Comment: I've literally answered that in the first sentence of my answer. Whether that matters: the last sentence of my answer. Obviously, your TDMA slot isn't infinitely shortly after the end of your reception, because radio signals are bound by speed of light. Get your latency requirements straight before wondering about this kind of things!

Answer (score 0):

Using a FEC inside your demodulation chain will add some latency due to its computation time.

Viterbi is the decoding algorithm for Convolutional Coding. Latency is probably linked to Traceback length and Constraint. It does not need to consume a full encoded frame to start delivering decoded bits.

Turbo product codes algorithm combines two Convolutional Coding and Interleaver.
Decoding process is done in iterations. I am not sure, but I believe that it needs a full frame inside decoder to deliver decoded bits. Latency is probably linked to number of iterations.

I think that Viterbi has smaller latency but also smaller correction gain than TPC.
You should be able to find latency values for Viterbi and TPC in FPGA IP datasheets.